# Regex - starts with OPERATION and must be followed by either an integer or double

Tags: java, regex

SO I have the follow input string

```
OPERATION: 12, 12.32, 54.3332
```

OPERATION can be any of MIN, MAX, SUM. The regex should accept strings that only start with any of those three words follow by colon and the followed by either integer or double.

I have been googling and fidling around for hours now before I decided to turn to you guys.

Thanks for your time!

EDIT:

So far I have ended with this regex

```
^[MAX:SUM:AVERAGE:MIN:(\\d+(\\.\\d+)?), ]+$
```

It matches "MAX: " as correct as well as "MAX:" and "MA: . It also matches the strings of the following format : "MAX: 12, 12.3323......"

Comment: Are there always exactly three numbers following your operation?

Comment: no, the number of integers/doubles is unknown, can be any but it must at least have 1 after the colon

Comment: FYI, this site is a great tool for playing with regexes: http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misunderstand the meaning of `[]`. These refer to single character alternatives.

So `[MAX:SUM:AVERAGE:MIN:(\\d+(\\.\\d+)?), ]` is either `M` or `A` or `X` or .... So something like `MMMMM` should also match.

You may want something more like this:

`^(MAX|SUM|AVERAGE|MIN): (\\d+(\\.\\d+)?(, (?=.)|$))+$`

**Explanation:**

`(MAX|SUM|AVERAGE|MIN)` is either `MAX`, `SUM`, `AVERAGE` or `MIN`.
`": "` refers to the actual characters `:` and space.
`\\d+(\\.\\d+)?` is what you had before.
`", "` refers to the actual characters `,` and space.
`(?=.)` is look-ahead. Checking that the following characters `(?=)` matches any single character (`.`) (thus not end-of-string) so there isn't a `", "` required at the end.
So `, (?=.)|$` is either `", "` not at the end or nothing at the end.

**Alternative: Not using look-ahead**

`^(MAX|SUM|AVERAGE|MIN): (\\d+(\\.\\d+)?(, \\d+(\\.\\d+)?)*)$`

[**Test for both**](https://ideone.com/F8kCsq).

[Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Answer (score 2):

```
(?:MIN|MAX|SUM):[ ]+\d+(?:[.]\d+)?(?:,[ ]+\d+(?:[.]\d+)?)*
```

**Explanation**

```
(?:MIN|MAX|SUM) - either one of the operations, non-capturing
:             - a literal :
[ ]+          - 1 or more space characters
\d+           - 1 or more digits
(?:[.]\d+)?   - optionally a literal . followed by 1 or more digits, non-capturing
(?:,...)*     - a literal comma and another number, 0 or more times, non-capturing
```

`[.]` could also be written as `\.` but putting magic characters in a character class instead is a best practice, same goes for using `[ ]` instead of a space.

**References**

- [Java Patterns](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Hope that helps.

Comment: The only problem with the above is that it required each field to be a double. It does not allow for integers.

Comment: `(MIN|MAX|SUM):[ ]+\\d+([.]\\d+)?([,][ ]+\\d+([.]\\d+)?)*` updated slightly to allow for ints

Comment: failed at my first attemp with -> MAX: 12

Comment: Current above is still not accurate in that it would allow something list: `SUM: 123., 2344.`. If the `.` is present there should be following digits.

Comment: You may want to link to, the somewhat newer, [Java 7 docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Answer (score 1):

`java.util.regex.Pattern` accept regular expression formed by group of Greedy format expressions. You can create group to divide your input string.

```
OPERATION: NUM, NUM, DECIMAL, DECIMAL
```

Your regular expression is:

```
([MIN,MAX,SUM]+):([0-9]{4}.[0-9]{2}),(...),(...),(...)
```

and use:

```
Matcher.group()
```

to iterate upon found groups.

Note: I supposed that your number format is "dddd.dd"